# Getting the right i18n while having multiple instances

Tags: node.js, internationalization

I have a module which contains a simple i18n configuration, similar to the following one:

```
var i18n = require("i18n");
module.exports = function(){
    i18n.configure({
        locales:['en', 'de'],
        directory: __dirname + '/locales'
    });
    i18n.translate = function(w){
       return i18n._(w);
    }
    return i18n;
}
```

My main class successfully uses this instance to make internationalization, but when I import this module in a new project which also has it's own i18n instance and locales, I'm noticing sometimes it makes the right translations, while others it's trying to get the translation from the wrong i18n file, resulting in the key saved as a new key/value pair in the wrong file and getting no translation.

How could I solve this issue? I know both instances doesn't have any key in common, so it would be great if I could have a way to keep always both locales available (tried the `register: global` but didn't work)